# select reference value based on range

Tags: sql

I have three tables as below, with one of them having the reference values. I need to count the size, 2 rows smaller than 20 for example, and then multiply it by the "smallerThan20" value in the reference table as a col in the output table: 2*20. I can think of how to count based on a range from table1, for example `sum (case when t1.size <20 then 1.0 else 0 end) as rownumlessthan20`, but really have no idea how to look up or join the second one. Many thanks for your help.

product info:

```
+-----------+---+
|. product  |size| 
+-----------+---+
|      apple| 10|
|     orange| 5 |
|       pear| 30|
```

reference info:

```
+---------------+------------+-------------
| smallerThan20 |largerThan20| largerThan50
+---------------+------------+------------
|      10       |     20     |.    30
```

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using `cross join`

```
select 
sum(case when t1.size <20 then 1 else 0 end)*smallerThan20 as rownumlessthan20,
sum(case when t1.size>20 then 1 else 0 end)*largerThan20 as rownumlargerthan20,
sum(case when t1.size>50 then 1 else 0 end)*largerThan50 as rownumlargerthan50
from product_info cross join reference_info
```

Comment: thanks but I got an error saying rownumlessthan20 is not an aggregate function..

Comment: @fahmin yea i added a first(rownumlessthan20)

Comment: @user3735871 . . . This is invalid SQL.  It is an aggregation query but has unaggregated columns in the `select` -- and no `group by`.